# Executing the function appear() appear inside If statement

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```
//Blinking of the letter " X " on the Screen
function blink() {
  document.getElementById('blinkText').innerHTML = "";
  setTimeout("appear()", Math.random() * 3000);
}

//Re-Appearing of the letter " X " on the Screen
function appear() {
  document.getElementById('blinkText').innerHTML = "X";
  setTimeout("blink()", Math.random() * 3000);
  return true;
}

// Counts the number of times a space bar is hit
var hit = 0;
window.onload = function hitSpace() {
  document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      hit = hit + 1;
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = hit;
    }
  }
  blink();
}

//To run function hitSpace() only when the letter "X" appears, else display 
alert

function checkForBlink() {
  if (appear() == true) {
    hitSpace();
  } else {
    alert("You are too slow!")
  }
}
```

basically what i cant do is, when the letter X appears on the screen i want to count using the function hitSpace() and if the spacebar is hit when the letter X is not there, display an alert message. Please help to rectify my function checkForBlink()

Comment: Why are you trying to call `hitspace()`? All it does is add an event listener, which was already done when the page was loaded.

Comment: So what do I do to make the spacebar hit count only when X is blinking? if the X doesnt blink and The spacebar is Hit i was it to show an alert message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `hitSpace()`. Check if the `X` is there in the `onkeyup` function.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      if (document.getElementById("blinkText").innerHTML == "X") {
        hit = hit + 1;
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = hit;
      } else {
        alert("Sorry, you're too slow");
      }
    }
  }
  blink();
}
```